# How to configure L2TP/IPSec PSK VPN on Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, vpn, l2tp

I have a Sonicwall Firewall running an L2TP VPN with a pre-shared key. I need to connect to that VPN from my Linux computer running Xubuntu 18.04. I've tried quite a few different guides that I could find, but all boil down to the same few steps:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp  network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

Once installed, reboot the computer, open network connections, click to add connection, select "Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol (L2TP)"

For my settings I have:
Gateway set to static IP of the VPN. Username and password are set. Password tested with store for only this user and store for all users. NT Domain is empty.

Under IPSec Settings...
Checked "Enable IPsec tunnel to L2TP host", Entered pre-shared key, left Remote ID empty, Phase1 Algorithms set to "3des-sha1-modp1024!" and Phase2 set to "3des-sha1!" both with and without ! at the end, Enforce UDP encapsulation checked (and tested unchecked)

Under PPP Settings...
Tried having default settings, then only MSCHAP and MSCHAPv2, then only MSCHAPv2, none worked.

When I click the network dropdown (where you'd choose a wifi network) and select the VPN in the "VPN Connections" menu, it spins for a bit then stops. The VPN remains disconnected and no error is given.

I do have access to the Sonicwall and can play with some of the configuration of the VPN, but it has to stay setup as L2TP/IPSec with a pre-shared key. The VPN works great for Windows and Mac.

I'm happy to provide screenshots, logs, whatever would be helpful.

Also, I ran:

```
sudo ike-scan ipaddress
```

Which returned:

```
Starting ike-scan 1.9.4 with 1 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/ike-scan/)
ipaddress    Main Mode Handshake returned HDR=(...) SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=SHA1 Group=2:modp1024 Auth=PSK LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration=28800) VID=... (SonicWall-7)

Ending Scan...
```

Thanks for your help!